# How can I publish a visual studio program to a network so the setup.exe file can simply be run?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publishing

I am currently running into an issue where I publish a program and the setup/installation runs perfectly fine on a local drive, but when I move this to a network and try to install the program from the network files I get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/152Vp.png)

Is there a different way I should publish the program? What steps can I take to make the program directly install instead of having to move the files to a local drive?

Here are the details of the error:
ERROR SUMMARY

```
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of O:\didt6615\Smart_Sensors\WRC\Lab + Tools + Docs + Info + Meetings\WRC Programs\NGK Query\NGK Query V 1.5\NGK Simplified.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://dpl9949w/NGK Simplified/NGK Simplified.application did not succeed.
        + Unable to connect to the remote server
        + No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (IP ADDRESS HERE)
```

Comment: Does the `Details...` button in fact provide further details, and if so, can you please add those to the question too? Preferably as *text* rather than an image.

Comment: If you want to publish to the Internet for download, it is recommended that you publish directly to From a UNC path or file share.Please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard?view=vs-2022#to-publish-to-a-file-share-or-path).